# COMSOL Circularl polarization

Tags: finite-element, boundary-conditions, computational-physics, electromagnetism, comsol

I'm having some problems trying to implement circularly polarized light in COMSOL Muliphysics.

For a isotropic homogenous media, I've obtained without problems the TE and TM reflectance curves. Following the Fresnel Equation application tutorial, I've defined a periodic port for incident light with Ex=1 Ey=i Ez=0 and output periodic port with Ex=1 Ey=i Ez=0. Then, I just insert Floquet periodic boundary conditions over the x and y planes of my rectangular structure. The results are somehow so goofy.

What do you think? is there any missing condition I've forgotten?

Comment: This question could also fit on the new [Materials Modeling SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Tyberius, as it is right now. I don't think that the questions is fit in there. It is too specific to Comsol, it might be better asked in their forum.